# i want to run flutter emulater by the samsung phone s 9 but this erorr was appear how can i fix it?

Tags: flutter

i want to run flutter emulater in samsung phone s 9 but this error was appear how can i fix it please

this is the built.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is the erorr

(

One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to D:\Fluuter course\flutter projects\crud_map\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
...
}

)

my phone is samsung s 9 (sm-G960F)